# storing dataset (instances of a C++ class) in hdf

Tags: c++, hdf5

I have an application which needs to store data to hdf file.

Is it possible to store dataset in hdf which is actually a C++ object? For example, I want to store data contained in object `a` below to a hdf file (hdf4 or hdf5) . Can I do this? If yes, I would appreciate if someone can show to do this. Thank you.

```
class A(){

public:
   A(int i, double j):i(i), j(j){};
   ~A();
   int i;
   double j;
   int* ai;
   vector<int> b;
   setValues(int i, double j){};
}

void main(){

  A *a;
  a = new A(10, 10.2);

  // Store this data to hdf4 or hdf5


  //
  A *a2;

  // now read in the data stored in hdf file and assign the value here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use compound types, and to explicitly map the struct members down to the fundamental types supported by HDF.

The only complication that I have found this with approach has been with lists and sequences.  One option is to store the list items in a different dataset and then refer to the start and end index.

For cases where the data is not contiguous or is more complex then one approach is to use a linked list type construct.  So for the following:

```
class A {
    int i;
    vector<int> b;
}
```

This is mapped into:

```
ADataset => { i, b_index };
BDataset => { value, next_index };
```

Records in 'ADataset' store a 'b_index'.  Each record in 'BDataset' contains the value for that record and then an optional next_index.  A sentinel value can be used for 'next_index' to know when to stop.

Answer (score 0):

If your class attributes were simple types (`int`, `float`, `char`… even arrays of such types), you could save them in a compound datatype.

In the example class you show, there is a STL `vector`. If you have STL containers, you'd probably better use [Boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). The output would be ASCII text that you can store inside an hdf5 file.

If storage efficiency is your major concern, then you should take care yourself of writing the `vector`s in a variable size array for instance, and more generally, do the conversion between STL containers (and/or custom objects) and whatever hdf5 datatype you choose to store them when exporting and importing your objects to and from your hdf5 file.